# Adding custom object on Action Plan failing

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to add a custom object to the Action Plan v3 Unmanaged app. I have gotten as far as being able to get to the visual force page to set-up the Action Plan and it is related to our custom object 'Client__c'. However when I click the Save button I get the following error thrown back:

```
        FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: sObject type 'Client' is not supported.
        If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' 
        after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call 
        for the appropriate names.

    Error is in expression '{!save}' in component <apex:commandButton> 
in page actionplancreation
```

It also comes back with an email referencing the following lines:

```
Class.ActionPlansUtilities.retrieveOwnersDataRelatedObject: line 1114, column 1
Class.ActionPlanCreationController.referedObjectOwnerInit: line 415, column 1
Class.ActionPlanCreationController.save: line 218, column 1
```

What can be done to resolve this issue? Please help, the Apex console is new to me and any answers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you made a reference to your new client object in the page or controller as "Client", but you need to use "Client__c". *This would be the API name of the custom object.*

If, you are adding fields from the Client as a child of the action plan, you may also need to refer to it as "Child__r" *which indicates it is a relationship*.